# Was the Sailor a Ghost Too?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-twilight-zone

In the *The Twilight Zone* episode "The Hitch-Hiker", Nan Adams picks up a sailor along the way. Now as we find out at the end of the episode, she was actually a ghost, as, presumably, was her car since she had actually wiped out when it blew a tire.

My question is: was the sailor that she picked up at the gas station also a ghost heading to his final destination "back to San Diego"? How could he have physically interacted with her, ridden in her phantasmic vehicle, and asked the guy at the gas station to "get this doll some gas"?

I suppose I could understand the gas station attendant seeing her. That could be written off as a simple "paranormal incident". But the fact that the sailor can see her and interact with her physically plain-as-day, surely has to mean he is also a recently-deceased individual?

Answer (score 1):

If the Sailor was dead he would also see the Hitch-hiker.

I would say that Nan Adams an her car are still in their physical form until she realize she is dead. That's why her car is in pre-accident condition apart from the tire. Because she only know how her car looked back then.

They only see what they want to see. They don't know they're dead. *Sixth sense music*

Comment: I'll add to this that Nan also interacted with a woman at her mom's house, who basically told her she (Nan) was dead.  In the [original radio play](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hitch-Hiker_(radio_play)), the "sailor" was a woman (Nan was a man named Ronald Adams) who, after exiting the vehicle, was picked up by a truck driver.  In this context, it's logical to believe that the sailor was never intended to be another dead soul.